# Converting PHP array to JS array in PHP itself

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Hey just a small thing I am stuck on.

I do have the structure ready for the JS array but I need to assign it to a variable like

```
var data ={ Php array }
```

Here is the structure of my php array: `https://imgur.com/a/LPbCqEu` This is just a part of the array.

My code looks like this:

```
$csvfile = 'Property_CSVTruncated.csv';
$handle = fopen($csvfile, 'r');

$jsData = array(
'properties' =>array()
);

$header = NULL;
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
$i = 0;
if (!$header) {
    $header = $row;
} else {
  $data = array_combine($header, $row);
  $fields = array(
    '_id' => $data['C4021040'],
    'index' => $i,
    'price' => $data['123'],
    'picture' => "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property01.jpg",
    'city' => "Calgary",
    'MLS# ' => $data['C4021040'],
    'address' => $data['6 ASPEN RIDGE LN SW'],
    'latitude' => $data['51.045681'],
    'longitude' => $data['-114.191544'],
    'Bed' => $data['123'],
    'Bath' => $data['123'],
    'capSpaces' => $data['T3H 5H9'],
     );
array_push($jsData['properties'], $fields);
}
$i++;
}

fclose($handle);
$str = "const data = ";
print($str);

header('Content-type: application/json');
json_encode($jsData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$jsonFile = fopen('csvTojs.js', 'w');
fwrite($jsonFile, json_encode($jsData));
fclose($jsonFile);
```

So basically I need that string 'var data = ' and then prints the array.

Anyway to do that in php itself?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you convert it into json and read the data. you can use `json_encode` in php.

Comment: `json_encode` is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

in server, echo json_encode($phpArray) and exit;
in callback of ajax or init js variable, parse json to array with JSON.parse('jsonString');

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode()

```
<script>
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($jsData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>
</script>
```

Or in your case:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($jsData);
exit;
```